# ngFor item of a list of string, I cannot use the item directly

Tags: angular

I have a model, which is a list of strings.

```
<span *ngFor="let item of model; let i = index">
  <input #inputField
         type="text"
         [name]="name + '_' + i"
         [(ngModel)]="item"  />
</span>
```

The previous piece of code throws the error :

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
>   ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object {
>   __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber: Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack: Getter,
>   originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString: value(), 4 de
>   plus… }
>   _AstToIrVisitor.prototype.visitPropertyWrite@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:27076:23

Although, the following works fine :

```
<span *ngFor="let item of model; let i = index">
  <input #inputField
         type="text"
         [name]="name + '_' + i"
         [(ngModel)]="model[i]"  />

</span>
```

My question is quite simple: why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `item` is a primitive value which is passed by value. 
Updating the value wouldn't do anything useful, because `ngModel` receives only a copy of the value.

With `model[i]` you pass a reference that can be used to update the value where it is stored.

Comment: Ok, but if my componend defines something like `@Input() model: string;`, does it get wrapped into some kind of reference type?

Comment: No, `string` is a value type and is passed by value (copy). If `item` were an object and you would use `[(ngModel)]="item.value"` then it would work.

Comment: I don't get why `[(ngModel)]` can be bound to a value when the value comes from the component, be not to a value when it come from a `*ngFor`

Comment: Because in this case it binds to a field of the component. That's a reference to a place where you want the value be read from and updated, but with `ngFor` it would update a copy of the value that has no related to the original place where you want it to be updated.